# Beaglebone blue suddenly not sending signal to motors

Tags: python, flask

I have created an API which is used via a web UI to control my BeagleBone Blue. The board itself controls two DC motors (for driving) and a servo motor (for turning a camera). My API receives the GET request from the UI to control the DC motors but for some reason the motors are not getting a signal. For the longest time (with the same exact code I am using now) it was working just fine. I used a volt-meter to check if a signal was being sent to the DC motors and no power is being sent. I have updated my board and made sure I have the latest version of RCPY. I am stumped as to why this is happening. The strange thing is the servo motor works perfectly fine (as it did originally).

Here is the code for my API:

```
import rcpy 
import rcpy.motor as motor
import rcpy.servo as srv
import rcpy.clock as clock
import time

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify, make_response
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('robocar.html')

@app.route('/servo/<duty>')
def move_camera(duty=0.0):
    global servo_duty
    if request.method == "GET":
        servo = srv.Servo(1)
        duty = max(min(1.0, float(duty)), -1.0)
    
        rcpy.set_state(rcpy.RUNNING)
        clk = clock.Clock(servo, 0.02)
        srv.enable()
        clk.start()
        
        servo.set(duty)
        time.sleep(1)
    
        clk.stop()
        srv.disable()
        
        return _corsify_actual_response(jsonify({"response": "200"}))
    else:
        return _build_cors_prelight_response()

@app.route('/drive/<speed>/<direction>')
def move_car(speed=0.0, direction=0):
    if request.method == "GET":
        motor1_channel = 1
        motor2_channel = 2
        speed = float(speed)
        direction = int(direction)
        wheel_speeds = [speed, -speed]
        
        if direction ==  1:
            motor.set(motor1_channel, wheel_speeds[0])
            motor.set(motor2_channel, wheel_speeds[1])
        elif direction ==  4:
            motor.set(motor1_channel, wheel_speeds[0])
            motor.set(motor2_channel, wheel_speeds[0])
            
            if speed >= 0.1:
                time.sleep(0.5)
                stop_car()
        elif direction ==  3:
            motor.set(motor1_channel, wheel_speeds[1])
            motor.set(motor2_channel, wheel_speeds[0])
        elif direction ==  2:
            motor.set(motor1_channel, wheel_speeds[1])
            motor.set(motor2_channel, wheel_speeds[1])
            
            if speed >= 0.1:
                time.sleep(0.5)
                stop_car()
    
        #time.sleep(20)
        #stop_car()
    
        return _corsify_actual_response(jsonify({"response": "200"}))
    else:
        return _build_cors_prelight_response()

@app.route('/brake')
def stop_car():
    if request.method == "GET":
        motor1_channel = 1
        motor2_channel = 2
        motor.set_brake(motor1_channel)
        motor.set_brake(motor2_channel)
    
        return _corsify_actual_response(jsonify({"response": "200"}))
    else:
        return _build_cors_prelight_response()
    
def _build_cors_prelight_response():
    response = make_response()
    response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', "*")
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', "*")
    return response

def _corsify_actual_response(response):
    response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Here is my javascript to make requests to the API:

```
servo_duty = 0.0

function moveCamera(duty) {
    servo_duty += duty
    servo_duty = Math.max(-1.0, Math.min(1.0, servo_duty))

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://beaglebone.local:5000/servo/" + servo_duty,
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        data: {},
        success: () => {
            console.log('ok');
        },
        error: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
}

function moveCar(speed, direction) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://beaglebone.local:5000/drive/" + speed + "/" + direction,
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        data: {},
        success: () => {
            console.log('ok');
        },
        error: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
}

function stopCar() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://beaglebone.local:5000/brake",
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        data: {},
        success: () => {
            console.log('ok');
        },
        error: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
}
```

When a request for the DC motors is sent to the board, I get a 200 response. No errors in the console or on the API side. Any ideas? (Sorry for the wall of code).

Comment: use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you get in variables - it is called `'print debuging'`

Comment: @furas I have already done this and it shows me that I get all the data as I'd expect. The duty is being set as it should.